# Metricbeat exits after a short period of time > "error fetching EC2 Identity Document: operation error ec2imd..."

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I'm trying to set up Metricbeat on Windows (self-managed). I'm following these steps (hopefully I'm not missing anything crucial): https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-installation-configuration.html

When I run Metricbeat:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Metricbeat> .\metricbeat.exe setup -e
```

It exits after a short period of time.

These are the most suspicious log lines:

> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:51.848+0200","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go","file.line":100},"message":"add_cloud_metadata:
> hosting provider type not
> detected.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:52.876+0200","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/provider_aws_ec2.go","file.line":91},"message":"error
> fetching EC2 Identity Document: operation error ec2imds:
> GetInstanceIdentityDocument, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3,
> request send failed, Get
> "http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document":
> dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connectex: A socket operation was
> attempted to an unreachable
> network..","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}

The full log:

> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.728+0200","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":783},"message":"Home
> path: [C:\Program Files\Metricbeat] Config path: [C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat] Data path: [C:\Program Files\Metricbeat\data]
> Logs path: [C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat\logs]","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.729+0200","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":791},"message":"Beat
> ID:
> 098e1f15-5744-4b6d-bcbf-aec3ffd9dfa1","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"} {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.838+0200","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1303},"message":"Beat
> info","service.name":"metricbeat","system_info":{"beat":{"path":{"config":"C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat","data":"C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat\data","home":"C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat","logs":"C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat\logs"},"type":"metricbeat","uuid":"098e1f15-5744-4b6d-bcbf-aec3ffd9dfa1"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.838+0200","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1312},"message":"Build
> info","service.name":"metricbeat","system_info":{"build":{"commit":"10b198c985eb95c16405b979c63847881a199aba","libbeat":"8.10.4","time":"2023-10-11T19:25:38.000Z","version":"8.10.4"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.838+0200","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1315},"message":"Go
> runtime
> info","service.name":"metricbeat","system_info":{"go":{"os":"windows","arch":"amd64","max_procs":8,"version":"go1.20.8"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.873+0200","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1321},"message":"Host
> info","service.name":"metricbeat","system_info":{"host":{"architecture":"x86_64","boot_time":"2023-11-04T12:11:48+02:00","name":"melshawaf","ip":["fe80::1b8e:4b8b:68e:430","169.254.195.57","fe80::e4f0:35a8:a4f7:8df3","172.28.0.1","fe80::f3fc:ac2c:5b83:7ef6","169.254.119.69","fe80::d94e:b18a:1022:5607","169.254.15.123","fde2:ff59:de69:8600:146:a034:128e:4e0","fde2:ff59:de69:8600:5574:b741:a839:8e4e","fe80::e47a:d8f7:1a7d:fa1f","192.168.8.103","fe80::97b8:d9dd:1375:6e34","169.254.120.209","::1","127.0.0.1","fe80::43fc:9ffa:6b3b:654c","192.168.208.1"],"kernel_version":"10.0.19041.3448
> (WinBuild.160101.0800)","mac":["cc:48:3a:67:9f:87","00:15:5d:33:f5:17","2c:db:07:55:46:ab","2e:db:07:55:46:aa","2c:db:07:55:46:aa","2c:db:07:55:46:ae","00:15:5d:26:2d:f1"],"os":{"type":"windows","family":"windows","platform":"windows","name":"Windows
> 10
> Enterprise","version":"10.0","major":10,"minor":0,"patch":0,"build":"19045.3448"},"timezone":"EET","timezone_offset_sec":7200,"id":"f9911b9f-723b-4439-9003-88dda1936bad"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.873+0200","log.logger":"beat","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":1350},"message":"Process
> info","service.name":"metricbeat","system_info":{"process":{"cwd":"C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat","exe":"C:\Program
> Files\Metricbeat\metricbeat.exe","name":"metricbeat.exe","pid":30380,"ppid":17624,"start_time":"2023-11-04T22:17:41.010+0200"},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:48.873+0200","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":329},"message":"Setup
> Beat: metricbeat; Version:
> 8.10.4","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"} {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.258+0200","log.logger":"cfgwarn","log.origin":{"file.name":"tlscommon/config.go","file.line":102},"message":"DEPRECATED:
> Treating the CommonName field on X.509 certificates as a host name
> when no Subject Alternative Names are present is going to be removed.
> Please update your certificates if needed. Will be removed in version:
> 8.0.0","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"} {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.259+0200","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"eslegclient/connection.go","file.line":108},"message":"elasticsearch
> url:
> https://localhost:9200","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.259+0200","log.logger":"publisher","log.origin":{"file.name":"pipeline/module.go","file.line":105},"message":"Beat
> name: melshawaf","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.285+0200","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"eslegclient/connection.go","file.line":108},"message":"elasticsearch
> url:
> https://localhost:9200","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.300+0200","log.logger":"tls","log.origin":{"file.name":"tlscommon/tls_config.go","file.line":179},"message":"'ca_trusted_fingerprint'
> set, looking for matching
> fingerprints","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.300+0200","log.logger":"tls","log.origin":{"file.name":"tlscommon/tls_config.go","file.line":199},"message":"CA
> certificate matching 'ca_trusted_fingerprint' found, adding it to
> 'certificate_authorities'","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.369+0200","log.logger":"esclientleg","log.origin":{"file.name":"eslegclient/connection.go","file.line":291},"message":"Attempting
> to connect to Elasticsearch version
> 8.10.4","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"} Overwriting ILM policy is disabled. Set `setup.ilm.overwrite: true` for enabling.
>
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.369+0200","log.logger":"index-management","log.origin":{"file.name":"idxmgmt/std.go","file.line":230},"message":"Auto
> ILM enable
> success.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.372+0200","log.logger":"index-management.ilm","log.origin":{"file.name":"ilm/std.go","file.line":118},"message":"ILM
> policy metricbeat exists
> already.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.373+0200","log.logger":"index-management","log.origin":{"file.name":"idxmgmt/std.go","file.line":365},"message":"Set
> settings.index.lifecycle.name in template to {metricbeat
> {"policy":{"phases":{"hot":{"actions":{"rollover":{"max_age":"30d","max_primary_shard_size":"50gb"}}}}}}}
> as ILM is enabled.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.383+0200","log.logger":"template","log.origin":{"file.name":"template/load.go","file.line":245},"message":"Existing
> template will be overwritten, as overwrite is
> enabled.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.686+0200","log.logger":"template_loader","log.origin":{"file.name":"template/load.go","file.line":159},"message":"Try
> loading template metricbeat-8.10.4 to
> Elasticsearch","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.745+0200","log.logger":"template_loader","log.origin":{"file.name":"template/load.go","file.line":127},"message":"Template
> with name "metricbeat-8.10.4"
> loaded.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.747+0200","log.logger":"template_loader","log.origin":{"file.name":"template/load.go","file.line":143},"message":"Data
> stream with name "metricbeat-8.10.4" already
> exists.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.747+0200","log.logger":"index-management","log.origin":{"file.name":"idxmgmt/std.go","file.line":266},"message":"Loaded
> index template.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> Index setup finished. Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and
> reachable)
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:49.747+0200","log.logger":"kibana","log.origin":{"file.name":"kibana/client.go","file.line":183},"message":"Kibana
> url:
> http://localhost:5601","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:50.150+0200","log.logger":"kibana","log.origin":{"file.name":"kibana/client.go","file.line":183},"message":"Kibana
> url:
> http://localhost:5601","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:51.848+0200","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/add_cloud_metadata.go","file.line":100},"message":"add_cloud_metadata:
> hosting provider type not
> detected.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"warn","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:17:52.876+0200","log.logger":"add_cloud_metadata","log.origin":{"file.name":"add_cloud_metadata/provider_aws_ec2.go","file.line":91},"message":"error
> fetching EC2 Identity Document: operation error ec2imds:
> GetInstanceIdentityDocument, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3,
> request send failed, Get
> "http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document":
> dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connectex: A socket operation was
> attempted to an unreachable
> network..","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}
> {"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2023-11-04T22:19:45.677+0200","log.origin":{"file.name":"instance/beat.go","file.line":996},"message":"Kibana
> dashboards successfully
> loaded.","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"} Loaded
> dashboards

Also here is my metricbeat.yml (comments removed):

```
###################### Metricbeat Configuration Example #######################
# =========================== Modules configuration ============================

metricbeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: true
  
# ======================= Elasticsearch template setting =======================

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  index.codec: best_compression

# =================================== Kibana ===================================

setup.kibana:

  host: "localhost:5601"

# ================================== Outputs ===================================

# ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://localhost:9200"]
  username: "metricbeat_user"
  password: "asdfjkl;"
  ssl:
    enabled: true
    ca_trusted_fingerprint: "caa8cfead8cd39a1e0fae0c199068cf7ee6f7dbc8fb7f7a94e8c3624c0ef7987"

# ================================= Processors =================================
processors:
  - add_host_metadata: ~
  - add_cloud_metadata: ~
  - add_docker_metadata: ~
  - add_kubernetes_metadata: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a network connection problem:

```
"error fetching EC2 Identity Document:"
```

and

```
"A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network..","service.name":"metricbeat","ecs.version":"1.6.0"}"
```

why do you use https://localhost:9200 instead of http?

Comment: The URL is correct, I used the MSI installer instead of the self-hosted and it worked fine